# What does "apañao" mean?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales

¿Qué significa "apañao"?

Aparentemente se usa exclusivamente en la región de Andalucía. Estaba hablando con alguien y dijo esa palabra pero no la pudo traducir.

¿Alguien sabe su significado y uso?

---

It is apparently used exclusively in the Andalucía region. I was talking with someone and he said the word but couldn't translate it.

Does someone know its meaning and usage?

Comment: remember that in some regions, past perfect verbs sometimes lose the letter d in its conjugation, it is totally a slang, but its pretty common, even in written Spanish.  example _ganao_ ganado, _cantao_ cantado

Comment: This word is used throughout Spain, not just Andalusia.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Talking about people, *apañado* (colloquially "*apañao*") means **mañoso**:

*Es un tío muy apañado. Se las arregla muy bien solo.*

Talking about things, *apañado* means **adecuado**:

*Tiene una casa muy apañada. No es grande, pero es muy cómoda.*

> apañado, da.
>
> 1. adj. Hábil, mañoso para hacer algo.
> 2. adj. coloq. Adecuado, a propósito para el uso a que se destina.
>
> (DRAE)

Answer (score 5):

We use it too in Catalonia, but I think it's more usual in Andalucía.

Apañao is the shortening of Apañado, that is composed from apañar. The [Real Academia Española](http://dle.rae.es/apa%C3%B1ado) defines it as:

> apañado2, da. (Del part. de apañar).
>   1. adj. Hábil, mañoso para hacer algo.

That is, a person that is skilled or tricky to do something. If I have to translate it to english, probably I'll use resourceful.

Answer (score 1):

And when we hear: "alguien esta apañao/apañado" means: "that person has problems".

Answer (score 0):

Apañado (silent "d" in Andalucia) describes someone who's very open and friendly.  A nice person, a kind person, a good person is "Apañado."

Soy gringo, pero pase dos años en Andalucia (Sevilla y Granada).  I'm American, but lived in Andalucia for a couple of years in the 1990s.

In Andalucia "andaluthia", they're proud of their special accent.  They use the Castillian "th" in the typical three cases: ci (like ciruela) ce (like cerveza) and z (like zebra).

AND only in Andalucia they eat the ending of their words.  It's very artful and fun!  Ten cuidado turns into Ten Cuidao!

I could be totally wrong.  But that's the way I learned it 20 years ago.

Comment: Silent 'd' in _Apañado_ and participles in general is not exclusive to Andalucia, but rather common in informal speech all over the Spanish speaking world.

Answer (score 0):

En Argentina, en mi experiencia. se usa algo más el verbo que el adjetivo. Sobre todo en la expresión: "Fulano se las apañó bastante bien" ="He pulled through quite well". "Veremos cómo 
me las apaño"="We'll see how I manage/get by")